# Google cloud task unreliable / UNUSABLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am using google cloud tasks to sync some files from my storage. They have proven to be very unreliable they sometimes queue and don't start executing for few minutes or more. When they do they are not shown in cloud tasks console.

I am using this code to queue tasks

```js
const taskRequest: ICreateTaskRequest = {
  parent: queuePath,
  task: {
    name: taskPath,
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      url: taskUrl,
      body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(taskData))
    }
  },
};
const task = client!.createTask(taskRequest);
```

Documentation is really scarce thx for any help

[image]

EDIT: got the same thing again wtf google ?

EDIT: added logs
https://quicknote.io/04fe9570-edb9-11ee-b8cf-a1e741b2cf64

EDIT:
After adding new batch of tasks they started working and run 6 out of 7 tasks and now one is hanging forever

[image]

EDIT: funniest thing is that gcloud list doesnt even show it hahaha

gcloud tasks list --queue=google-drive-0p0F2CL7NKX1buIVax254c8kbdr2
WARNING: We are using the App Engine app location (europe-west1) as the default location. Please use the "--location" flag if you want to use a different location.
Listed 0 items.

Queue setup:

Location
europe-west1
Rate limits
Max rate
500/s
Max concurrent
1000
Max burst size
100
Retry parameters
Max attempts
100
Min interval
0.100s
Max interval
3600s
Max doublings
16
Max retry duration
Unlimited

Comment: You may observe this kind of behavior when Tasks per second (TPS) exceed the recommended rate of 500. To troubleshoot, you can check the Cloud Tasks console for errors.

Comment: Also If you have more than 5,000 tasks, some tasks are not visible in the Google Cloud console. Use [`gcloud CLI`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/tasks/list) to view all tasks.

Comment: I have 7 tasks which should each be done in few seconds its nothing demanding. They are just not starting

Comment: What do the logs show? Put those details in your question.

Comment: Queue logs are disabled by default and its not like it is happening every time if i am able to catch the logs i will post them @JohnHanley just really disappointed in the tech currently everything i try fails XD

Comment: Are you able to find the logs? If so, please edit your post by adding logs?

Comment: I believe i have been able to find out the cause. Since my function would catch an error i didnt send a response then and it would hang. Since i can not see the tasks in the UI i can not verify that

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue by sharing the minimal reproducible steps? Or the Documentation you are following?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni you sound like an AI haha

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni added same 7 task again now it started working WTF is this some kind of preview software or what ? It only added 6 actually :shoutgun: